# Printing a map from an atlas for more than one sheet in QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas

I created an atlas for aggregated buildings by the appropriate attribute. I need to create a 1:2000 scale map on an A3 sheet of paper. I have 507 groups of buildings printed on 507 sheets. Unfortunately, I can't cope with a situation when the printout does not fit on one sheet. In this case, I would like the atlas to create two sheets (or more) so that all the buildings of the appropriate class are shown on the map (they are shown in yellow in the picture). How to do it with an atlas?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide details on how you currently control your atlas.

Comment: Added to the question